# How do I measure time between clicks?

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch, milliseconds

I've been making a small project for myself trying to measure time between 2 clicks. Later on I will change it to key presses but that I can do on my own. I need to measure the time in milliseconds and the only way I knew about was to use timer...

```
    bool clicked = true;
    int time = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clicked)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            clicked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            clicked = true;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time += 10;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(time);
    }
```

The timer is set with the interval of 10 ticks and just to visually see I also made the timer display the time. But when I was testing it, I added another timer with the interval of 1000 ticks and by that I saw the difference. I later on realized the timer is inaccurate. I started digging and the only thing that was being recommended was stopwatch and I tried this...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = new Stopwatch();

        if (clicked)
        {
            timer.Start();
            clicked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
            label1.Text = timeTaken.ToString();
            clicked = true;
        }
    }
```

But that returns the result of "00:00:00" every time. What do I do?

Comment: `var timer = new Stopwatch();`  This is declared local to the method.  Try moving it to the form level.

Comment: Try the ``Stopwatch();`` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a timer, you just have to compute the time elapsed between the first click (store the date and time it occured in the `dtPreviousClick` variable) and the second one.
The difference between 2 `DateTime` objects is a `Timespan` objects which has a property named `TotalMilliseconds` which is the value you're looking for.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds

```
bool clicked = false;
DateTime dtPreviousClick;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!clicked)
  {
    dtPreviousClick = DateTime.UtcNow;
    clicked = true;
    label1.Text = "awaiting another click....";
    
  }
  else
  {
    label1.Text = (DateTime.UtcNow - dtPreviousClick).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
    clicked = false;
  }
}
```